Getting erro while running celery worker in prefork mode
I have an flask app and i am setting up an celery in that app. But when i am calling my api which is running an celery task. I am getting error:
Error:
[2024-10-15 01:58:00,820: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-1' pid:11307 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2024-10-15 01:58:00,835: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV) Job: 0.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/piyushedra/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/truecrawler-WjSH7bMq-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1265, in mark_as_worker_lost
    raise WorkerLostError(
billiard.einfo.ExceptionWithTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/piyushedra/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/truecrawler-WjSH7bMq-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1265, in mark_as_worker_lost
    raise WorkerLostError(
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV) Job: 0.

I am getting this error again and again.
I am using this command to run my celery worker: celery -A server.celery worker --queues=pre_crawl_queue --pool=prefork --loglevel=INFO --hostname=pre_crawl_queue@%h
But when i doing --pool=solo or --pool=threads it's working but i want to do it using prefork since i want multiprocessing.
My verisions:

celery: "^5.4.0"
sqlalchemy = "^2.0.35"
psycopg = "^3.2.3"
psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.9"
Postgresql = 14

Please answer this if anybody knows how to fix this issue. Please comment if any other information is required.

Could you please share the error messages in plain text instead of an image?

Hey @FrankHeikens. Updated the error message in question itself.

With Celery you need to use billard, not multiprocessing, in your tasks.

Yes, I want multiprocessing in my celery. So, have 5-6 queues and i want to deploy worker for each queue on server which can consume task from the queue.
